# Reverse proxy fails on https on nginx for windows

Tags: nginx

I have set up a vps to redirect to middle ware pc. The middle ware has windows nginx with is config

```
worker_processes  1;



events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    
    
    sendfile        on;
    tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

   
    server {
        listen       443;
        server_name 192.168.1.80:443;
        

         location / {
          
            proxy_pass https://192.168.1.80:443;
        }

        
    }

}
```

The vps has Debian with this config

```
    server { 
    listen 2323; 
    proxy_pass xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443;  (external ip of middle ware)


    #ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.crt; 
    #ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key; 
} 


#
}
```

It connects via http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2323 to 192.168.1.80 of target.

but fails if I try https: and i need to to connect with https

What am i missing

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have commented out these two lines:
#ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
#ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert.key;
Please remove the "#" symbol and execute the command:

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

For further clarification, could you please provide the log files, including access.log and error.log, located at /var/log/nginx/

Comment: access logs are empty. Error logs have ```2023/05/23 09:10:17 [error] 160061#160061: *1705 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: 0.0.0.0:2323, upstream: "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:443", bytes from/to client:0/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/0```